Errors when creating HRUs - "cannot convert float NaN to integer
When attempting to create HRUs a keep getting the following error message:
2024-05-05T12:37:11     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users/evanw/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QSWAT3_9\QSWAT\hrus.py", line 398, in readFiles
              OK = self.CreateHRUs.generateBasins(self._dlg.progressBar, self._dlg.progressLabel, root)
              File "C:\Users/evanw/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QSWAT3_9\QSWAT\hrus.py", line 2379, in generateBasins
              elevation = int(elevation * self._gv.verticalFactor)
             ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

I've tried I few different tables to try to identify the problem each resulting in the same error. None of the input datasets have any NaN values and looking at the error it looks like it is in the HRU files that are supposed to generate. Anyone else have this issue?
